$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$. Can we represent this as a finite degree polynomial function?
$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order n up to isomorfism.
It is possible to represent $f(n)$ as a finite degree polynomial function?
Something like this:
$$a_{0} + \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} \cdot n^{i} = f(n)$$
For a fixed positive integer $k$.

$f(n)$ is not even bounded above by any polynomial! See here.

$f(n)$ heavily depends on the prime factorization of $n$. There is not even a closed form formula , in particular $f(n)$ is unknown for some relatively small $n$.

Short version

Suppose $f(n)$ is a finite degree polynomial function.
If $n$ is a prime number, then $f(n)=1$
$\#\{n \in \mathbb{N} | f(n) = 1\} = \infty$
$n \in \mathbb{N} \implies f(n) = 1$
$f(4) = 2$
This is a contradiction.
$f(n)$ is not a finite degree polynomial function.

Long version

Suppose $f(n)$ is a finite degree polynomial function.
Let's define $g(n) = f(n) - 1$
If $f(n)$ is a finite degree polynomial function, then $g(n)$ is a finite degree polynomial function.
If $n$ is a prime number, then $f(n)=1$.
If $n$ is a prime number, then $g(n)=0$.
There are infinite prime numbers.
$g(n)$ has infinite roots.
If $n=4$, then $f(n)=2$
If $n=4$, then $g(n)=1$
If $n=4$, then $g(n) \neq 0$
$g(n)$ is not a finite degree polynomial function.
This is a contradiction.
$f(n)$ is not a finite degree polynomial function.


Well, kinda sorta.  Many people define $\mathrm{deg}(0)=-\infty$, or just leave it undefined.

+1 but that is a fairly long answer for such a simple idea: $f(n)=1$ inf8nitely often, which is only possible if $f(n)=1$ for all $n,$ which is obviously not true.. Just write the short version at the top - you can keep the long version, but the short version is much clearer.
